# TDD: why might it be wrong to let app code know it is being tested, not run?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, tdd

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348260/should-source-code-know-its-being-tested), Brian (the only answerer) says "Your code should be written in such a fashion that it is testing-agnostic"

The single comment says "Your code should definitely not branch on a global "am I being tested flag".".

But neither gives reasons, and I would **really** like to hear some rational thoughts on the matter. It would be immensely easy (particularly given the fact that a lot of tests have package-private access to the app classes) to reach into a given app class and set a boolean to say "this is a test, not a run".

All sorts of things which I find myself jumping through hoops (injected mocked private fields, etc.) to achieve could become easier to accomplish.

It's also obvious that if you took this too far it could be disastrous... but as one tool among many in the software testing armoury why does the concept meet with such opprobrium?

**Answer to Mick Mnemonic:**

A trivial example of how this might help would be if you're actually creating a new class instance in the middle of a method and assigning it to a private field: private field mocks won't help in that case because you are replacing the private field.  But actually creating a real object might be very costly: you might want to replace it with a lightweight version when testing.

I encountered such a situation yesterday, in fact... and my solution was to create a new package-private method called createXXX()... so I could mock it. But this in turn goes against the dictum "thou shalt not create methods just to suit your tests"!

Comment: TL;DR: The production code should not depend on tests. It should be the reverse. (Otherwise your tests can affect the behaviour of your production code, and that's not something you'd want to happen)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what "TL DR" means. Why does having a boolean variable constitute "dependency"?  I really want to understand.

Comment: _"TL;DR" means "Too long didn't read". I said it to let you know I was giving a brief response to your question._ --- A boolean doesn't automatically constitute a harmful dependency in my opinion. It depends on how it's used. He probably means that you shouldn't have `if(TEST_MODE)` scattered inside your production code.

Comment: Could you give an example of code that would benefit from it knowing to be running under test?

Comment: Give me a sec to write up an answer.

Comment: @mike, the example you give, to me, seems solvable via dependency injection. I.e. you could inject a factory for creating these objects into your class-under-test, and for your unit tests, mock the factory to create lightweight versions.

Comment: Ooh, that's an interesting-sounding idea. I suppose it would nonetheless involve minimal departure from the most basic, basic obvious way of creating an object, and arguably that departure would have been induced by TDD requirements...  But OTOH maybe the use of a factory like that would be a "good design choice" in its own right. Food for thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will split this answer into two sections. First I'll share my thoughts on Brian's answer, then I'll share some tips on how to test effectively.

### An explanation of Brian's answer

There appear to be two key ideas that Brian is hinting at. I will address each one individually.

#### Idea 1: Production code should not depend on tests

> Your code should be written in such a fashion that it is testing-agnostic.

The production code should *not* depend on tests. It should be the reverse.

There are multiple reasons for this:

1. Changing your tests will **not change the behaviour** of your code.
2. Your production code can be compiled and **deployed independently** of the test code.
3. Your code **won't need to be recompiled** when updating the tests.
4. Your production code **cannot possibly fail** due to unintended side effects from not running the test code.

*Note:* Any decent compiler will remove the test code. Although I don't think this is an excuse to poorly design/test your system.

#### Idea 2: You should test abstractions rather than implementations

> Whatever environment you test in should be as close to real-world as possible.

It *sounds* like Brian might be hinting at this idea within his answer. Unlike the last idea, this one isn't universally agreed upon, so take it with a grain of salt.

By testing abstractions, you develop a level of respect for the unit being tested. You agree that you will *not* hoke around with its internals and spy on its internal state.

> Why shouldn't I spy on the state of objects during testing?

By spying on the innards of an object, you are causing these problems:

1. Your tests will **tie you to a specific implementation** of a unit.

   For example...
   Want to change your class to use a different sorting algorithm? Too bad, your tests will fail because you've asserted that the `quicksort` function *must* be called.
2. You will **break encapsulation**.

   By testing the internal state of an object, you will be tempted to loosen some of the privacy that the object has. This will mean that more of your *production* code will also have increased visibility into your object.

   By loosening the encapsulation of your object, you are tempting other production code to also depend on it. This can not only tie your *tests* to a specific implementation, but also your entire system itself. You do *not* want this to happen.

> Then how do I know if the class works?

Test the pre-conditions and post-conditions/results of the method being called. If you need more complex tests, look at the final section I've written on **mocking** and dependency injection.

#### Mini note

I don't think it's necessarily bad to have an `if (TEST_MODE)` in your main method **as long as** your production code remains independent of your tests.

For example:

```
public class Startup {

    private static final boolean TEST_MODE = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (TEST_MODE) {
            TestSuite testSuite = new TestSuite();
            testSuite.execute();
        } else {
            Main main = new Main();
            main.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

However, it becomes a problem if your other classes *know* that they're running in test mode. If you have `if (TEST_MODE)` throughout all of your production code, you're opening yourself up to the problems I've mentioned above.

Obviously in Java you would use something like JUnit or TestNG instead of this, but I just wanted to share my thoughts on the `if (TEST_MODE)` idea.

### How to test effectively

This is a very large topic, so I'll keep this section of the answer short.

- Instead of spying on internal state, **use mocking and dependency injection**.

  With mocks, you can assert that a method of a mock you've injected has been called. Better yet, the dependency injection will invert your classes' dependency on the implementation of whatever you've injected. This means you can swap out different implementations of things without needing to worry.

  This completely removes the need to hoke around inside your classes.

---

If there was one book I'd strongly recommend reading, it would be *Modern C++ Programming with Test-Driven Development* by *Jeff Langr*. It's probably the best TDD resource I've ever used.

Despite having C++ in the title, its main focus is definitely TDD. The introduction of the book talks about how these examples should apply across all (similar) languages. Uncle Bob even states this in the foreword:

> Do you need to be a C++ programmer to understand it? Of course you don't. The C++ code is so clean and is written so well and the concepts are so clear that any Java, C#, C, or even Ruby programmer will have no trouble at all.

Comment: Thanks... I'll have to digest all of this. I may well try to get hold of that book, although I have already worked through Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided by Tests, and actually spent a long time actually working through the auction example. C++ is not a language I ever got into much, and I wonder whether it'd be possible to work through his exercises in say Java...?

Comment: Despite having C++ in the title, its main focus is definitely TDD. The introduction of the book talks about how these examples should apply across all (similar) languages. Uncle Bob even states this in the foreword: `Do you need to be a C++ programmer to understand it? Of course you don't. The C++ code is so clean and is written so well and the concepts are so clear that any Java, C#, C, or even Ruby programmer will have no trouble at all.`

Answer (score 3):

Think of the big Volkswagen scandal.  A system which behaves differently under test than under production load isn't really tested.  That is: it is really *two* systems, the production system and the test system - and the only one of these which is tested is the test system.  The production system, being different, is not tested.  Every difference in behavior you introduce between the two systems is a testing vulnerability.

Comment: A classic case. If you want to know more about this, find one of Uncle Bob's talks called "Expecting Professionalism". He brings it up quite a lot.

Comment: I bow to your far superior knowledge, expertise and experience (and rep) of course.  But I did say "It's also obvious that if you took this too far it could be disastrous."  As a hugely inexperienced TDDer, one thing I'm already aware of is not to put too much faith in the "completeness" of your tests.  Arguably they will never be "complete". So you could say that another risk (or vulnerability) of TDD is its tendency to think you've woven a web of total security around your classes. Which leads me to think, ultimately, that there should be "measure in all things".

Comment: Agreed (not about my knowledge and all that, but that things can be taken too far).  But there are practices which lead in dangerous directions, and introducing different behavior into test and production systems is one of these.  I think Brian's advice was sound.

Comment: Understood.  However, thinking about it, I'm pretty much persuaded many mocking techniques can in fact introduce artificial state and artificial behaviour ("dangerour directions"). A dramatic example might be if you mock a class or method which in production goes off and does all sorts of crazy things, such as spawning new threads which might interfere with your CUT in some way. Are you sure these matters are quite so cut-and-dried?

Comment: The thing is with mocking you are (or should be) mocking parts of the production code which aren't relevant to the system under test.  So that's considerably safer than changing the system under test.

Comment: Ah, yes... that's the distinction. Right.

Answer (score 2):

> a lot of tests have package-private access to the app classes

I would advise against this, the idea of breaking encapsulation in production code feels like the tail wagging the dog to me. It suggests that the classes are too large and / or lack cohesion. TDD, dependency injection / inversion of control, mocking and writing single responsibility classes should remove the need for relaxing visibility.

> The single comment says "Your code should definitely not branch on a global "am I being tested flag".".

Production code is production code and has no need to know about your tests. There should be no logic concerning tests in there, it's poor separation. Again, dependency injection / inversion of control would allow you to swap in test specific logic at runtime, that won't be included in the production artifact.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. As you might have surmised, I'm a TDD newb (I've been getting to grips with the practicalities of it over the past 4 or 5 months, as well as reading books, etc.). I'm sure I'm doing lots of things wrong, probably testing in too fined-grained a way, etc. But I rarely find that tests are confined neatly to one class and that "swapping in logic" is that easy to accomplish. Sigh. TDD really is an art, and I'm a lowly apprentice.

Comment: @mikerodent I found this very useful - I saw the guy at devox, a Java conference. Well worth a watch, it helped me out. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHnuMjah6ps

Answer (score 1):

I read all these answers quite closely and they are all helpful. But perhaps I should reclassify myself: I appear to be becoming a low-intermediate TDD practitioner, rather than a newb. A lot of these points and rules of thumb I have already assimilated, either by reading or by sometimes baffling, occasionally bitter but always instructive experience over the past 6 months or so.

Carl Manaster's analogy with the Volkswagen scandal is seductive but slightly inapplicable, perhaps: I am not suggesting that the app code should "detect" that a test is happening and alter its behaviour as a result.

What I *am* suggesting is that there are one or two knotty, bothersome low-level problems where you might want to use this tool in a way that does not interfere in any way with the cast-iron rules and "philosophy" of TDD.

Two examples:

I have a few cases in my code where exceptions are thrown, and tests where I want to check they are thrown. Fine: I go `doThrow( ... )` and `@Test( expected = ... )` and everything works fine.  But during a production run I want an error message to be printed out with a stack trace.  During a test run I just want the error message.  I don't want the `logback-test.xml` to suppress error-level logging completely.  But apparently there is no way to configure a logger to prevent printing out the stack trace.

So what I can do is to have a method like this in the app code, contrived solely for testing:

```
boolean suppressStacktrace(){ return false; };
```

... and then I use that as a test for a given `LOGGER.error( ...` situation, and then mock that method to return `true` when I want to provoke that exception during testing.

Secondly, the rather specific case of console input: `BufferedReader.readLine()`. Substituting another `InputStream` for `System.in` and feeding it with a `List` of different `Strings` which will be served up once per `readLine` is a right pain in the provberbial.  What I have done is to have a `private` field in the app class:

```
Deque<String> inputLinesDeque;
```

... and a `package-private` method to set this with an `List<String>` of input lines, which can then be `pop`ped until the `Deque` is empty. During an app run this `Deque` is `null`, so an `if` branches to `br.readline()` instead.

These are just 2 examples. No doubt there are other situations where the ultra-purist approach comes at too high a price, and arguably procures no real benefit.

However, I appreciate davidxxx's superior definition of one of the TDD 10 commandments: "thou shalt not create methods to suit your tests and that open the API of the application in an undesirable way". Very helpful: food for thought.

***later***

Since writing this a month ago I've realised it's far from impossible to extend and modify `logback` classes... I assume it wouldn't be too difficult to make your own `logback` class that would indeed accept a configuration flag in `logback-test.xml` to "supress stack traces".  And of course this bespoke `logback` class wouldn't have to be exported when you make an executable jar of your app ... but again, to me this comes in the category of "jumping through hoops".  How "pure" does app code really need to be?

Answer (score 0):

> TDD: why might it be wrong to let app code know it is being tested,
>   not run?

1) Carl Manaster has brought a excellent and short answer. If your implementation has a different behavior according to that is tested or not, your test has no value as it doesn't reflect the real behavior of the application in production and therefore it doesn't validate the requirements.

2) Test-Driven Development has no relation with the fact to let app code know it is being tested. Whatever the development methodology you use, you may introduce this type of error.

With my TDD experience, I think that TDD prevents from letting the app code know it is being tested since as you write the unit test in first intention and you do it suitably you have the guarantee to have a naturally testable applicative code that validates the app requirements and that has no knowledge of the tested code.

I imagine rather that this kind of error could happen more probably when you create the test code after writing the applicative code as you may be tempted to not refactor the applicative code to make your code testable and so to add some tricks in the implementation to bypass the refactoring task.

3) Test-Driven Development is code that works but you cannot forget the design aspects of your app classes and your test classes when you use it.

> A trivial example of how this might help would be if you're actually
>   creating a new class instance in the middle of a method and assigning
>   it to a private field: private field mocks won't help in that case
>   because you are replacing the private field. But actually creating a
>   real object might be very costly: you might want to replace it with a
>   lightweight version when testing.
>
> I encountered such a situation yesterday, in fact... and my solution
>   was to create a new package-private method called createXXX()... so I
>   could mock it. But this in turn goes against the dictum "thou shalt
>   not create methods just to suit your tests"!

Using the package-private modifier is in some cases acceptable but it should be used only if all natural ways of designing your code don't allow to have an acceptable solution.

> "thou shalt not create methods just to suit your tests"
>   may be misleading.

In fact I would say rather : **"thou shalt not create methods to suit your tests and that open the API of the application in an undesirable way"**

In your example, when you want to modify a dependency of your code that you would like mock or substitute a dependency during test, if you practice TDD you should  not modify directly the implementation but start the modification by the test code.
And if you test code seems blocked because you miss a constructor, a method, an object, etc... to set a dependency to your tested class, you are forced to add in your tested class.
 It is the TDD way.

Above, I referred to not opening the API more than needed. 
I will give two examples that provide a way of setting a dependency but that don't open the API in the same way.

This way of doing is desirable because the client cannot change the behavior of MyClass in production :

```
@Service
public class MyClass{
...
MyDependency myDependency;
...
@Autowired
public MyClass(MyDependency myDependency){
   this.myDependency = myDependency;
}
 ...
}
```

This way of doing is less desirable because the MyClass API grows while the applicative code doesn't need it. Besides with this new method, the client can change the behavior of MyClass in production by using the setter of myDependency field:

```
@Service
public class MyClass{
...
MyDependency myDependency;
...
@Autowired
public void setMyDependency(MyDependency myDependency){
   this.myDependency = myDependency;
}
 ...
}
```

Just a remark : if you have more than 4 or 5 arguments in your constructor, it may become cumbersome to use it.
If it happens, using setters is still probably not the best solution as the root of the problem is probably that the class has too many responsibilities. So it should be refactored if it is the case.